# SSD Size Dissapearing

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, filesystem, ssd

I recently have been low on SSD space, I can usually manage with very little space.

Today I decided to try to create a Windows VM on VirtualBox. I did a "df -h" to check my disk space left and it said I had about 8GB available of 110GB. After allocating a 5GB hard drive of the virtual machine I realized that windows needs at least 8GB to install. I removed the virtual machine uninstalled virtualbox (apt-get purge virtualbox.)

After the installation I did another "df -h." I realized that I only had about 2GB left on my system. It seems as if the virtual hard drive never got deleted. I ran a search for and virtual hard disks and I couldn't find any. I decided there may have been a glitch, so I restarted my computer. When my computer booted back up df reported that the size of my SSD was now 103GB instead of the previous 110GB as if the space magically disappeared. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Note: My operating system is Kubuntu 14.04. Since this question has nothing to do about kde as far as I'm aware of I thought this would be a good place to post this.

Comment: This is always a good place to ask about Kubuntu (and other official derivatives), related to kde or not ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find a suspected big file/folder by running this, it will tell you all files/folders sizes:

`du ~ -h|sort -r -n|less`

it will also sort so the biggest file/folder will go first at the top of your screen.

And don't forget to clean the Trash/Rubbish Bin anyway.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer but that doesn't seem to fix the problem I am having. I did a search for files that were 5GB and none turned up that were suspicious. I looked at recently modified files by sorting them by access time and nothing suspicious popped up there.